# Knockout Js with Jquery UI Datepicker - "Missing instance data for this datepicker"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a date declared as an observable in my view model like this:

```
self.date = ko.observable(date);
```

In my markup, I am declaring the control like this:

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control datepicker" 
        data-bind="
            datepicker: date, 
            attr: { 
                id: 'Payments_' + $index() + '_Date', 
                name: 'Payments[' + $index() + '].Date'
            }
        "
        data-dateformat="dd/mm/yy" 
        data-val="true" 
        data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." 
        data-val-required="The Date field is required."
    />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

This is used in a Knockout JS Template and I am trying to make it place nice with the out of the box ASP.Net MVC model binding for a collection of a custom object.

I am using the following Knockout JS custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || { dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' };
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    //update the control when the view model changes
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            current = $(element).datepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};
```

My problem is that when a value is selected in the Datepicker, I get the following error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker 
t.extend._getInst 
t.extend._selectDay
t.extend._attachHandlers.e.dpDiv.find.map.e.selectDay 
x.event.dispatch jquery.js:4692x.event.add.y.handle
```

If I remove the attribute binding for setting the Id and Name of the control then the error does not occur. I need to be able to set this though so that the MVC Model binding can interpret it correctly. Any suggestions or ideas would be very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What version of knockout, 2.x or 3.x ?  I'm also assuming that this HTML snippet is in a foreach binding (due to use of $index)

Comment: I have found a working example of date picker at http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2014/07/knockoutjs.html under heading Integrate third party widgets with knockout

Comment: @RobertSlaney yes you are correct. I left out the foreach for brevity. I'm using knockout 3.1.0. G_S thanks but that example doesn't use an ID for the data bound control and that is my problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that when the datepicker binding is applied, the id hasn't been set yet. And from what I could find online, the id is key to how the datepicker works, the datepicker is associated with the id. If it ever changes, it usually leads to problems.

Since you are using knockout 3.1, you can add the `after` property to your binding handler and include the `attr` binding to the list. This will ensure that the listed bindings are applied first before this one. And with the `attr` binding applied, the element should have an id by then.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    after: ['attr'], // add this
    init: ...,
    update: ...
};
```

Just beware that since your ids are being updated as you add/remove your payments.  If a change alters the id of an existing control, it will detach the associated datepicker and you will see the problems again.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcbbvqgv/)

Comment: Thanks, helped me out.